# Handling code of multiple ASP.NET websites based on the same template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC and have to develop and deploy multiple websites based on a first website.
There are variation in some controllers, some views, some scripts and some models, and the Database are different on each website (mainly columns are differents but table names remains the same).
Is there a way to handle such a thing in a single Visual Studio Project, in order to make maintaining easier, and be able to add common feature easily on every website ?

Currently, I copy the pilote project into a new VS project, and change all the variation. But I find it's not an ideal situation (because of maintaining/improving).

Comment: You would need to find a way to abstract out the parts that are different so that modifying the template doesn't break the implementations. That may require a significant rearchitecture, and you're not going to find an easy way to go about this.

Comment: I thought about base and derived class, but I'm not sure on how to handle this in a MVC pattern (it's my first ASP.NET application).

Comment: It's going to be a far bigger reachitecture than some base and derived classes. It's really too broad of a thing to ask about on Stack Overflow: if you want to handle this cleanly, you have to spend a significant amount of time thinking how to factor out the differences. It's not something we can help with.

Comment: I am not to sure what the question is entailing what do you want to keep and what you don't want. As far as I imagine creating a base application as a template and inserting different connection strings is inevitable. Again please specify what features you would like to see on all of the websites?

Comment: My sites will have the same number/name of pages, only the content of the pages will change. Content is mainly formatted tables, plus few interaction to add/edit/remove data to the tables

Comment: @hervai so just use the template project and change the minor details, don't see why you need to go about doing it in one VS project, just gonna get messy and there is no added benefit to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something like that years ago and can give some general advice you might find useful.

First of all developing app with such "multitenancy" has nothing to do with MVC pattern itself. You can do that without MVC :D. Second, if the websites supposed to work with different business domains I am afraid there is no generic way to do what you want. In my case it was just a number of e-commerce platforms.

Anyway, consider next things.

1.Think about using sub-domain approach if you can. It will free you from stupid routing and cookies shenanigans. Basically you can map `*.yourdomain.com` to one app and handle the necessary logic related to tenant easily. So in my case it was an application that behaved differently depending on provided url, not route, but sub-domain, `'superclient.yourdomain.com'` for example. Its not always possible or good idea, but think about it.

2.Dependency Injection everywhere. Well, its useful in general but in your case is absolute must have - try abstract any tenant specific logic in separate types and init them in one place. Its everything related to localization, timezone settings, app theme, branding info on the app header etc. Just initialize and inject where its needed. If you have something like

```
if (website1) {
    showBlockOne();
} else if (website2) {
    showBlockTwo();
} else if (website3) {
    showBlockThree();
}
```

then you doing something wrong, its a road to insanity. It should be something like

`_currentTenantViewContext.ShowBlock()`;

So its polymorphism over conditional operators in most cases.

3.In my case the requirement was to create an app which can work with any language so I had to handle that issue on database side as well. The problem is that if usually you have lets say for example `ProductType` table in database with `Id` and `Name`, in multitenant application its not that simple. My solution was to create two tables - `ProductType` with Id and `Code` fields and `ProductTypeLocalization` table with Id, `ProductTypeId`, `LanguageId`, `Value` fields to handle this problem. Requirement also was to make this values editable from admin panel...

I don't know is it the case for you, but if yes think about it before the shit hits the fan in future.

4.For situations where you need some specific fields in some database table only for one site its not a good idea to spawn them freely (in general). Consider using some generic format for that, like JSON or XML. If you have few additional text fields for specific website in some table just create one field (call it ExtraSettings or something) and store this strings as JSON in that one field. Of course you have to handle this data in separate way, but its about dependency injection again. 
Also you can use NoSQL for that.

5.Provide feature toggling, different websites requires different blocks to be displayed, rules applied etc. You have to have some way to on/off them for particular website(tenant) without recompile/redeploy.

Hope it helps.